# How do I open Xcode 13.4.1 in OSX Ventura 13.1?

Tags: xcode, macos

**I've tried using the finder:**
Applications Folder > Find Xcode App > Right click on the app and click on Show Package Contents > Open Contents > Open MacOS > and launch Xcode.

**I've tried from the command line:**
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode

The result is this error block:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode ; exit;  JKnee1@APCVMD6M5288FF
objc[2579]: Class ASVError is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/GPUToolsCore (0x12f48d050) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GPUDebugger.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/GPUToolsASVC.framework/Versions/A/GPUToolsASVC (0x12ebf4338). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[2579]: Class DYShaderAnalyzerNextGPU is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/MTLToolsShaderProfiler.framework/Versions/A/MTLToolsShaderProfiler (0x12f926c60) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/GPUTools/PlugIns/GLToolsShaderProfilerMobileSupport.gtplugin/Contents/MacOS/GLToolsShaderProfilerMobileSupport (0x143fb99c0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Answer (score -1):

Silly answer. Just `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode` without the `open` to start the command from the command line. tada.

Comment: Why not run it like any other app? Double-click on the icon in the Applications folder.

Comment: that doesn't work because ventura technically supports xcode 14. not 13. this is a workaround for 13.

Comment: The thing is, it's an unsupported workaround. Plus, this is _not programming_ so it arguably shouldn't be on Stack Overflow.